# Current URL in hyperlink for Joomla tpl file

Tags: url, joomla, smarty

i have the joomla TPL file, its has hyper link with

`{$ROOT_HOST}/&liststyle=grid`

i need to replace the {$ROOT_HOST} with the current URL and its full parameters to include the grid style tab # to the end of the current url. this is done in tpl file.

SO can any one tell me if there is a possibilty to include the #grid to the Current page url(parameter)

`<a href="{$ROOT_HOST}/&liststyle=grid"></a>`

I tried {$CURRENT_URI} but didnt work still getting the main host url!.
please help :)

Comment: Have you tried `JURI::current()`?

Answer (score 0):

you should be using JURI like MasterAM stated http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current